# Rename Files and Add Bracket to Years of Movies

Tags: regex, rename

So Basically What I am trying to achieve is Rename my movie folder names and add bracket to years (also replace dots with spaces)

I am using `rename` command with Regex

This is how Movie names are :

```
La.chambre.des.officiers.2001
The.2nd.2020
The.Song.of.Names.2020
```

This is How I want them to be :

```
La chambre des officiers (2001)
The 2nd (2020)
The Song of Names (2020)
```

I used the Following Regex :

```
Match: (.+ )(\d\d\d\d)

Replace: \1(\2)
```

And Finally,this was my Rename command

```
rename -v 's/(.+ )(\d\d\d\d)/\1(\2)/'
```

Unfortunately nothing happened

What can I do to fix it..Thanks

PS : I am looking for a pure CLI solution rather than any GUI solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of how this could be solved with links to regex101.com to try them out

This will replace the periods

```
Match = '/[\s\.]/m';
Replace = ' '
```

https://regex101.com/r/Hn01d7/1/

This will put brackets around our year

```
Match = /(.)(\d\d\d\d)/gm;
Replace = `\1(\2)`;
```

https://regex101.com/r/mRX88I/1

I am currently not on a *nix machine and so am not able to try this out.

But to do this in CLI,

use `rnm` like this

`rnm -y -rs '[Regex]' [FileLocation]`

where `-y` will confirm all changes without asking
`-rs` replace string command
'[Regex]' is your regex statement
'[FileLocation] is where all your directories are. use ./* for all

eg: `rnm -y -rs ''s/(.+ )(\d\d\d\d)/\1(\2)/'' ./*`

use link below as reference;

https://neurobin.org/docs/unix/rnm/bulk-rename-in-linux#41-search-for-files-with-regex-and-rename

Comment: Thank you for answering..But How can I integrate it with ``rename`` command

Comment: I have updated my answer. let me know how that answers you